# Where should I load data in from a firebase in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiviewcontroller, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having trouble trying to figure out where I should load in the data from Firebase into my app. I'm not sure where to load the data into ***viewDidLoad*** or ***viewWillAppear***. I am currently loading data in ***viewDidLoad*** but when I visit another view controller that add items to Firebase to be displayed by the previous view controller. But when I pop back to the original view controller it doesn't show an update in the view controller that supposed to show the item that were updated or added to the database.

Comment: Update in view did load and post a notification on change and observe it where you need to reload with ‘NotificationCenter’

Comment: This is a vague question that's hard to answer; If the view you *leave* doesn't go out of scope and has an observer on the data it needs then the Firebase closure within that view will automatically get called whenever there's an add, change or remove of the data it's observing. Likewise, when you *pop back* to the first controller it could be simply following a segue back or perhaps returning from a call back function. If that's the case, simply call the Firebase function at that point to refresh. Can you clarify the question as you're going to get some random answers without more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice for your case is `viewWillAppear` as it's being called when you pop back , so make sure to free the array and load it again if it's not a child add observation

Comment: Is there any way to access Firebase cached data inside the device and make the changes/updates there instead of fetching all these data again from Firebase? Because if the data we refer to are of significant volume, then its a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad()` is only called **once** after the controller is loaded into memory (more info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload).

If you want to update your data when you go back to your controller, you should do it in `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidAppear()`. The later is called after the former so it's your choice where to call the update function.

In addition, you can also update immediately when there is new data by using `NotificationCenter`, without the need to go back to your controller.